# How to change the font of my TeX editor on Mac?

Tags: texshop

I use an editor named TeXShop, but there appears to be no choice for the font in this editor.

The font here is not for appearing in the final pdf file, but the font in the editor when I type.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the Prefs of TeXShop, you choose the font of the source (what you see on the screen) :

[image]

And then `\usepackage{fourier}` or `\usepackage{lmodern}` or some other package in your preamble to set the font for your pdf.

Answer (score 5):

Its right there in the Preferences:

TexShop->Preferences...

Top left of the dialog is the setting for "Document Font"

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, I wanted a quick answer to the same question because editor font does not appear to be adjustable from the TexShop system preferences. On my mac with TexShop v 2.47,

`source`→`font`→`bigger` (or `smaller`)

work. I had to stumble around for a minutes to find that menu location, but the shortcuts are more obvious

<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>equal</kbd> (for `bigger`, b/c "<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>equal</kbd>" is a plus sign)

<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>minus</kbd> (for `smaller`)

... hopefully this saves someone 4 mins of grief ...